# Java - object reference to other object

Tags: java, object

A little confused about object reference in Java. As I understand it, when I say:

```
Obj objA = new Obj();
Obj objB = objA;
```

I'm assigning objB a *reference* to objA. So if I change either I'll change the other. This is in fact how it works with Arrays. Say I pass `Boolean[] a = {false, false}` to the following method:

```
Boolean[] test(Boolean[] a){
    Boolean[] b = a; //Array object = Array object
    b[0] = true;
    System.out.println("In method:");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("%d ", a[i]?1:0);
    }
    System.out.println();
    return a;
}
```

On return, `a[0]` is now true. But say instead I pass the same thing to:

```
Boolean[] test2(Boolean[] a){
    Boolean[] b = new Boolean[2];
    b[0] = a[0];  //Boolean obj = Boolean obj
    b[0] = true;
    System.out.println("In method:");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("%d ", a[i]?1:0);
    }
    System.out.println();
    return a;
}
```

If I return a now, `a[0]` will still be false. (It works the same if I say `b = new Boolean(true);`) But what's the difference? In both cases I said Object = Object. Why does the reference work in the first but not in the second? Furthermore, is there a way to get the same functionality where one cell refers to another the way one array refers to another?

Comment: I believe primitives like Boolean and Ints are not by reference. You are essentially assigning `b[0]=false;`  There's a good SO question on it in JavaScript that I'm trying to find that explains it clearly.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Nothing to do with primitives (and `Boolean` isn’t one). You’re overwriting a reference rather than modifying the object referenced.

Comment: A "reference" in Java is actually a pointer, and does not correspond to what is called a "reference" in other languages like C++.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ryan but can you please tell me what this is a duplicate of? Because I spent about 10 minutes putting different versions of this question in the search box.

Comment: @jimboweb: The duplicate is linked at the top of the question.

Comment: "I'm assigning objB a reference to objA."  Not exactly.  _Both_ of these are now references to some _other_ object living on the heap somewhere.  You can change the contents of that object and it'll be reflected in both places, but you can also make `objB` point to something new and `objA` won't change at all.